# Select from the first dropdownlist box is supposed to populate second dropdownlist with related values. My code is not doing that. Any ideas?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net

This is supposed to be easy. I have done it successfully a ton of times.

I select an option from drodpwonlist1 and the second dropdownlist gets populated based on select fro dropdownlist1.

For some reason, the code below is not working.

Please have a look at simplified version of the code:

'//markup:

```
        <div class="ui-widget">
           <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlUsers" runat="server" placeholder="Select a user..." AppendDataBoundItems="True" Width="300px"  OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlUsers_SelectedIndexChanged">
       <asp:ListItem Value=""></asp:ListItem>
      </asp:DropDownList>
      </div>
       <br /><br />
        <div class="ui-widget">
           <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlDates" runat="server" Enabled = "false" placeholder="Select a date..." Width="300px">
       <asp:ListItem Value=""></asp:ListItem>
      </asp:DropDownList>
      </div>

'//Code behind:

    Public Sub PopulateUsers()
        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("select DISTINCT c.userid,c.userName from tblUsers c " & _

                        "Inner Join tblInstructors i on c.instructorId = i.instructorId " & _
                        "ORDER BY c.userName ASC", New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("DBConnectionString").ConnectionString))
        cmd.Connection.Open()

        Dim ddlValues As SqlDataReader
        ddlValues = cmd.ExecuteReader()

        ddlUsers.DataSource = ddlValues
        ddlUsers.DataValueField = "userId"
        ddlUsers.DataTextField = "userName"
        ddlUsers.DataBind()

        cmd.Connection.Close()
        cmd.Connection.Dispose()
    End Sub

    Protected Sub ddlUsers_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
        ddlDates.Items.Clear()
        ddlDates.Items.Add(New ListItem("--Select a date--", ""))

        ddlDates.AppendDataBoundItems = True
        Dim strConnString As [String] = ConfigurationManager _
                   .ConnectionStrings("DBConnectionString").ConnectionString
        Dim strQuery As [String] = "select DISTINCT d.dateId, d.TrainingDates from tblTrainingDates d " & _
                        "Inner Join tblCourses c on d.dateid=c.dateid " & _
                        "WHERE c.userId = @userId ORDER BY d.TrainingDates ASC"
        Dim con As New SqlConnection(strConnString)
        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand()
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userId", _
                             ddlUsers.SelectedItem.Value)
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
        cmd.CommandText = strQuery
        cmd.Connection = con
        Try
            con.Open()
            ddlDates.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader()
            ddlDates.DataTextField = "dateId"
            ddlDates.DataValueField = "TrainingDates"
            ddlDates.DataBind()
            If ddlDates.Items.Count > 1 Then
                ddlDates.Enabled = True
            Else
                ddlDates.Enabled = False
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            Throw ex
        Finally
            con.Close()
            con.Dispose()
        End Try
    End Sub
```

If there is a match between userid from first dropdownlist and second dropdownlist, enable second dropdownlist and populate related values.

The second dropdownlist is not getting enabled, neither are associated values getting populated.
Any ideas what I could be doing wrong?

Comment: Does the page have AutoEventWireup set to true? Does the "--Select a date--" item get added?  Perhaps step through the code and make sure that event is firing and if so, see what sql statement is being generated and run it yourself against your SQL database and makes sure rows come back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is not working becouse you forget the `AutoPostback=True`

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlUsers" runat="server" placeholder="Select a user..." AppendDataBoundItems="True" Width="300px"  OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlUsers_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostback="True">
       <asp:ListItem Value=""></asp:ListItem>
      </asp:DropDownList>
```

Wihtout that the event **OnSelectedIndexChanged** never will fire.

Comment: @Freak_David, you probably won't believe me but I did have AutoPostBack set to true before I removed it.

I probably won't believe me too but it is working now, WOW!

Thanks alot

Comment: @Kenny Don't worry :)